# Using same EC2 instance for node and mongo hosting

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-ec2

Can I use my aws EC2 instance to run both node server and mongo server by installing mongo driver into my EC2 instance ?

Its gotta be just like how we do it in our localhost, right?

Comment: Yes, it is going to be the same as the localhost. Everything! Go ahead and try!.

Comment: I used it for more than 3 months. And recently when my db processes needed more computation, I had to separate them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd rather advise you to separate concerns and have dedicated instances for nodejs and for mongodb. It's not only good practice to separate app and db but also you'll able to scale much easier, and you'll scale exactly what you need.

Comment: I now use AWS Lambda and AWS DynamoDB instead!